# Redirect Current Tab From Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

How can I redirect the current tab when a button in a panel is clicked?

What I currently have in my code right now is the following :

**Javascript**

```
function doSearch (){
  alert("Search!"); 
  var tabs = require("tabs");
  tabs.open("http://google.com");
}
```

**XUL**

```
<xul:panel>
  <xul:hbox>  
    <button onclick="doSearch ()">Button 1</button>   
  </xul:hbox>
</xul:panel>
```

Comment: When you say "redirect", do you mean to have the currently active tab navigate to that URL?

Comment: Yes, navigate not redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by "redirect" you mean "navigate to"... how about this?

```
function doSearch (){
  var win = window.top.getBrowser();
  var tab = win.selectedBrowser;
  tab.contentWindow.location.href = "http://google.com";
}
```

That should be OK provided your XUL is an overlay to the ChromeWindow hosting the TabBrowser in question.

See [MDN: Tabbed Browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser) for some other scenarios.

Comment: actually selectedBrowser would be the current window no?

Comment: I think it's the current Tab (a `Browser` element), which then contains the "content" window.

Comment: ah you're right i misworded it. what i meant was if the button was somehow clicked when it wasnt the focused tab then this script would load the selected tab. its defintely the browser element in the tab. but its unlikely that button is clicked when window not focused, just if firefox hangs

Comment: I think the presumption is that the button itself not placed on a "Tab", per se, but on a higher-level (i.e: chromeWindow toolbar) part of the interface. At that level, it's relevant to ask, which "Tab" `is selected`, rather than, does the chromeWindow hosting this "Tab" `have focus`. Otherwise, as you imply, it's a tautological question.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend this:

```
function doSearch (e){
var win = e.target.ownerDocument.defaultView;
  win.alert("Search!"); 
win.top.document.location.href = "http://google.com";
}

document.YOURBUTTON.addEventListener('click', doSearch, false);
```